# 301 Redirect with characters at the end of the link

Tags: http-status-code-301, post-redirect-get, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I disable my AMP plugin and i have two type AMP Pages and want to want to redirect them to orginal pages these pages with 301 redirect:

https://example.com/post-name/?amp=1

https://example.com/post-name/amp

to

https://example.com/post-name

I try this but it just redirect /amp and not redirect ?amp=1

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/amp(.*)$

RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

i find it

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /?amp=1

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1? [L,R]